# Django app goes haywire when deployed. Race conditions?

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, web-deployment, django-2.1

I wrote a django app for quizzing, and it checks the user's answers and updates scores as soon as the user submits an answer. Here is the corresponding view to do this -

```
current_question_key = 0 #This is a global variable.
def check_answer(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_team = Team.objects.get(user = current_user)
    current_score = current_team.score

    if request.method == "POST":
        answer = request.POST.get('answer')
        question = Question.objects.get(id = current_question_key)
        if answer == question.answer:
            if question in current_team.questions_answered.all(): #This is required to prevent the score from increasing if the somebody submits a correct answer to the same question more than once
                pass
            else:
                current_team.score = current_score + question.score_increment
                current_team.questions_answered.add(question)
                current_team.save()        
        else:
            # This is required to prevent the score from decreasing if someone has answered it correctly earlier
            if question in current_team.questions_answered.all():
                pass
            else :
                current_team.score = current_score - question.score_increment//negative_marking_factor
                current_team.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=204) #This means that the server has successfully processed the request and is not going to return any data.
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error404")
```

The value of current_question_key is changed from the view used to send the question to the front end -

```
def game(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":
        key = request.POST.get('questionKey')
        global current_question_key
        current_question_key = key
        question = Question.objects.get(id = key)
        question_text = question.question_text
        data = {
            'question_text':question_text
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        current_user = request.user
        current_team = Team.objects.get(user = current_user)
        score = current_team.score
        name = current_user.username
        return render(request, 'Base/main.html', {'teamname':name, 'score':score})
```

When tested on django's development server, this worked perfectly fine even when around 10 people were using it simultaneously. But, as soon as I tried to serve it with nginx (hosted on my laptop, with 5 simultaneous users), the app went totally haywire and even correct answers were evaluated as wrong.

I tried apache too and had the same problem with it. Almost all requests were handled incorrectly. Could this be related to race conditions? What exactly might be going on here?

Comment: Where does `current_question_key` come from?

Comment: It is a global variable. My bad. Forgot to mention.

Comment: How is that global variable set? Is it a constant or does it change with user input?

Comment: I just edited the question. It is set using another view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a global variable like this in Django. A Django application usually runs in multiple server processes which do not share memory. Calling the `game` view would only set the global variable `current_question_key` in one of the processes. All other processes would still have old values. As a request can be served by any process, you get more or less random results.

The Django development server uses multi-threading instead of multi-processing. Threads, as opposed to processes, share the same memory, so all request see the same value for `current_question_key`.

You have to store `current_question_key` for each user in a way that is accessible to all processes. The most obvious solution would be to store this information in the user's [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/):

```
request.session['current_question_key'] = ...
```

Alternatively, you could store it in the database, e.g. with `ForeignKey` in a [customer user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), or if you want to keep track of games any in a separate table like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

class Game(model.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

You can then get the current game for a user by sorting by creation date:

```
Game.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-created_at').first()
```

Depending on how often the current question changes, you could also consider using a key-value like Redis, although that complicates things a bit.

Comment: But the question is supposed to be different for different users. How can I store it in the database? Then it would become universal for all users. Furthermore, if what you're saying is the case, why did the app run fine on the development server?

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I wanted to clarify - each user has a different value of current_question_key in the game, since they might be on different questions. So what exactly do you mean by "so all request see the same value for current_question_key"? If all requests see the same universal value of the variable, the app would still fail.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I mean that all requests *by a certain user* receive the same value. You could also solve this using sessions, I extended my answer accordingly.